# When should I use app/libs in cakephp 1.3?

Tags: cakephp

I baked new app in cake1.3 and I've noticed new 'libs' directory in app root. What is it purpose and/or when should I use it?

Answer (score 4):

"In addition to app/vendors a new app/libs directory has been added. This directory can also be part of plugins, located at `$plugin/libs`.

Libs directories are intended to contain 1st party libraries that do not come from 3rd parties or external vendors. This allows you to separate your organization's internal libraries from vendor libraries.

App::import() has also been updated to import from libs directories."

from [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1572/New-features-in-CakePHP-1-3).

Comment: that url is invalid now use this one :http://book.cakephp.org/view/1572/New-features-in-CakePHP-1-3